# How to convert the given input array to the following output using dataweave?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Input

```
{
  "Ids": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

Output

```
["Ids": "1", "Ids": "2", "Ids": "3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the map() function to map each element. Note that each element in the output array is an object, which in JSON is represented between curly brackets.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Ids map {ids: $}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "ids": "1"
  },
  {
    "ids": "2"
  },
  {
    "ids": "3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Isn't there a way just to have "ids": "1" and not have them enclosed in an object? ["ids": "1", "ids" : "2", "ids": "3"] ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense in JSON at least. What are you trying to do with the output?

Comment: No, man I think I got you, my bad! Thanks :D, the broader use case is to call a salesforce query the number of times there are Ids, so if there are 5 ids in the array , then the same sf query should be called 5 times with those 5 individual ids. So was trying to use a parallel for each for it.

Comment: If you are using it with the Salesforce Connector you'll want to use application/java instead of JSON. If you print the output you will see represented similar to JSON but in memory they are Java lists and maps.